# How much grain will fit in a 16 liter kettle?

Tags: all-grain, mash-volume

I'm considering to buy a 16 liter kettle to hold the grain inside my 32 liter kettle, but don't seem to find any reliable calculations on how much grain the 16 liter kettle will fit while mashing.

Does anyone here have a formula for calculating the maximum grain in a container?

Comment: Are you looking to store dry grain, hold wet grain, or to do a mash?

Comment: Please explain having a kettle inside another kettle.

Comment: I'm thinking of changing from a bag (BIAB) to a kettle for the grain during mash. Something like this: http://beer.suregork.com/?p=2065

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the "Can I mash it?" calculator at http://www.rackers.org/calcs.shtml

According to that, 8 kg of grain will fit with enough water for 1.25 liters/kg mash thickness with .64 liters of headspace.